# pyxeleditor: command not found (pyxel module)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyxel

I am racking my brain here as I have installed pyxel (2d python gaming module) and everything runs fine HOWEVER I can't load up the pyxeleditor.

I run the command:

```
pyxeleditor resources.pyxres
```

and get the error

```
bash: pyxeleditor: command not found
```

I get that it is not being recognised as a command but have no idea why. Any ideas ?

The official github repo is pretty popular for Pyxel but nobody seems to  be having this particular issue.

Cheers

Comment: What's the output on ```pip freeze | grep pyxel```?

Answer (score 0):

If you read [How to Create Resource](https://github.com/kitao/pyxel#how-to-create-resource) in the README, you'll see that the command is `pyxel edit ...`. Nowhere does it mention `pyxeleditor`. The `pyxel` script is located in your `Scripts` directory, whose location varies depending on your platform, how you installed Python, and how you installed Pyxel.